# CS0103: The name **** does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

The code worked before I did nothing other than added another variable and a getter to it.
Now everything doesn't work.
The .NET version of all the projects in the solution is the same (4.7).
[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0ODL.png)

I cannot run the project anymore as it doesn't start properly ([there's an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3gyh.jpg)).
What is going on? This has been happening for months now. The answer I got from my seniors is that it's a matter of the solution being that huge that Visual Studio mishandles it occassionally and thus this error is the resulting mishap. The difference is that this time, restarting Visual Studio/my computer didn't "solve" it. I tried with those restarts after cleaning and rebuilding didn't achieve anything.
Does anyone know what to do?

**The code worked before I added <%# GetCssClass %>** to the .ascx file. After I added that, everything became broken, and even when I undo adding that, nothing still works.

**.ascx**

```
    <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="EventICTGenerator.ascx.cs" Inherits="CMSApp.CMSWebParts.MyCompany.DetailPages.Event.EventICTGenerator" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/CMSWebParts/MyCompany/Controls/ICSCalendarControl.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="ICSCalendarControl" %>

<uc1:ICSCalendarControl runat="server" ID="ICSCalendarControl" LinkCssClass='event-header__info-actions-save <%# GetCssClass %>' 
      ResourceString="MyCompany.event.SaveTheDate"
      EventName='<%# EventName %>' 
      EventLocation='<%# EventLocation %>' 
      EventAddress='<%# EventAddress %>' 
      EventStartDate='<%# EventStartDate %>' 
      EventEndDate='<%# EventEndDate %>' 
      EventSummary='<%# EventSummary %>' />

<%# Position %>
```

**.ascx.cs**

```
using CMS.DocumentEngine;
using CMS.Helpers;
using CMS.PortalEngine.Web.UI;

using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace CMSApp.CMSWebParts.MyCompany.DetailPages.Event
{
    public partial class EventICTGenerator : CMSAbstractWebPart
    {
        protected string EventName = "";
        protected string EventLocation = "";
        protected string EventAddress = "";
        protected DateTime EventStartDate = DateTime.Now;
        protected DateTime EventEndDate = DateTime.Now;
        protected string EventSummary = "";
        protected int widgetPosition = -1;

        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);
            if (!StopProcessing)
            {
                SetupControl();
                BindEventData(EventDocumentID);
            }
        }

        private void SetupControl()
        {
            BindEventData(EventDocumentID);
            this.DataBind();
            widgetPosition = Position;
        }

        protected string EventDocumentID
        {
            get
            {
                return ValidationHelper.GetString(GetValue("EventID"), string.Empty);
            }
        }

        protected string EventLink
        {
            get
            {
                return ValidationHelper.GetString(GetValue("Link"), string.Empty);
            }
        }

        protected int Position
        {
            get
            {
                return ValidationHelper.GetInteger(GetValue("Position"), -1);
            }
        }

        protected string GetCssClass
        {
            get
            {
                return Position switch
                {
                    1 => "generic-content_align generic-content_align–left",
                    2 => "generic-content_align generic-content_align–center",
                    3 => "generic-content_align generic-content_align–right",
                    _ => "",
                };
            }
        }

        protected string EventLinkText
        {
            get
            {
                return ValidationHelper.GetString(GetValue("LinkText"), string.Empty);
            }
        }

        private string LinkTextAndUrl()
        {
            return $"{EventLinkText} <{EventLink}>";
        }

        private void BindEventData(string documentID)
        {
            TreeNode item = DocumentHelper.GetDocuments("MyCompany.Event")
                .Columns("EventName, LocationName, LocationAddress, ShortDescription, Date, EndDate")
                .OnCurrentSite()
                .WhereEquals("DocumentID", documentID)
                .FirstOrDefault();

            if (item != null)
            {
                string summary = ValidationHelper.GetString(item.GetValue("ShortDescription"), string.Empty);

                this.EventName = ValidationHelper.GetString(item.GetValue("EventName"), string.Empty);
                this.EventLocation = ValidationHelper.GetString(item.GetValue("LocationName"), string.Empty);
                this.EventAddress = ValidationHelper.GetString(item.GetValue("LocationAddress"), string.Empty);
                this.EventSummary = $"{summary}\n{LinkTextAndUrl()}";
                this.EventStartDate = ValidationHelper.GetDateTime(item.GetValue("Date"), DateTime.Now);
                this.EventEndDate = ValidationHelper.GetDateTime(item.GetValue("EndDate"), DateTime.Now);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've had the IDE complain about these things at design time but still work at run time.  Is that the case here?  Or does the page also fail at run time with the same error?

Comment: It doesn't work. I've attached an image of the page that shows after running the project to the beginning of the post.

Comment: The runtime error looks very different, though they may have the same root cause.  Have you tried and full clean and re-build of the application?  You can get even more drastic by deleting the project entirely and then re-fetching from source control and building fresh.

Comment: I've tried the clean and re-build. I'd like to know the reson for this and having to clone the project anew is frustrating on many levels.. It's possible I'll end up trying it because I need to do my job..

Comment: Try cutting your UserControl down to a do nothing shell and see if it then compiles. If it does, and functionality back slowly.

Answer (score 0):

What "solved" was this changing my switch-case.
I inputted it like

```
 switch
                {
                    1 => "generic-content_align generic-content_align–left",
                    2 => "generic-content_align generic-content_align–center",
                    3 => "generic-content_align generic-content_align–right",
                    _ => "",
                };
```

VS was telling me that my switch case was not good, and that's why I changed it to that form to begin with. It then didn't tell me anything's wrong with it or in any way point me to it. -.-
Now that I've changed the way that that switch case is writtern voila, it works.